# Why does Perl just give me the last line in the file?

Tags: perl, file

I have downloaded the following file: [rawdata_2001.text](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2001.text)

and I have the following perl code:

```
open TEXTFILE, "rawdata_2001.text";
while (<TEXTFILE>) {
    print;
}
```

This however only prints the last line in the file.  Any ideas why? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file is formatted with carriage returns only, so it's being sucked in as one line.  You should be able to set $/ to "\r" to get it to read line by line.  You then should strip off the carriage return with chomp, and be sure to print a new line after the string.

Comment: my code now looks like this:

    $/ = "\r";
    open TEXTFILE, "rankorder/rawdata_2001.text";
    while (<TEXTFILE>) {
      print;
    }

Still no luck though, still only prints the last line

Comment: Sorry that comment is very hard to read(not sure how to format comments correctly).  But anyway I added $/ = "\r"; to the top of the perl program, but still no changes.  Any other ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

your file probably is using `"\r"` line endings, but your terminal expects `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`.  try running:

```
open my $textfile, '<', "rawdata_2001.text" or die;
while (<$textfile>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
}
```

you can also experiment with changing the input record separator before the loop with `local $/ = $ending;`, where `$ending` could be `"\n", "\r\n", "\r"`